# It is related to PHP and css for wordpress blog

Tags: php, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have installed a complete blank theme with no CSS in my new wordpress blog. I have been trying to give it a background image but no success.

I am working on blog's content. Blog is very new. So, until content is ready, I want just a background image to appear on my blog and have some text in the middle of the page.

I removed content from footer.php, I removed default post which you see when Wordpress is first involved. I removed content in searchform. php too. I want it all blank for sometime. just want a BG image and some text that displays in the middle of my blog.

I added this line in blank theme's style.css..its not working. ALso where do I add text so it displays in the centre?

```
body { background: url('http://mysite.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/myIMG.jpg')
```

Can some one please help me out here??

I do not know anything about PHP so I dont knwo where to add text. Please help me. Which php whould I add text to? and also this background image isnt still working. I changed "background" to "background-image" now

this is the only css file in my Wordpress blog as of now..I have been making changes in this only.

```
/*
Theme Name: BlankSlate
Theme URI: http://tidythemes.com/blankslate/
Description: BEFORE USING AND ESPECIALLY UPGRADING PLEASE READ: tidythemes.com/concept. The bare essentials of a WordPress theme, no visual CSS styles added. Perfect for those who would like to build their own theme from scratch or for clients if you're a developer or designer. This theme is clean, valid code, semi minified, no programmer comments, SEO-friendly and 100% open source. One custom menu and one widgetized sidebar to get you started. If you don't know CSS and would like to learn we've prepared: tidythemes.com/want-to-learn-css and please visit us in the forum for further help: tidythemes.com/forum - Thank You and Enjoy
Author: TidyThemes
Author URI: http://tidythemes.com/
Version: 2.0
Tags: custom-menu, featured-images, microformats, sticky-post, threaded-comments
License: GNU General Public License v2.0 | From TidyThemes: This theme is completely free and open source to use as you like for both personal and commercial projects without any limitations.
License URI: http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html
*/
body { background-image: url('http://mysite.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/myIMG.jpg')  !important; no-repeat}
body { text-align: center !important;}
html{  margin-top:0px !important;}

html,body,div,span,applet,object,iframe,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,p,blockquote,pre,a,abbr,acronym,address,big,cite,code,del,dfn,em,img,ins,kbd,q,s,samp,small,strike,strong,sub,sup,tt,var,b,u,i,center,dl,dt,dd,ol,ul,li,fieldset,form,label,legend,table,caption,tbody,tfoot,thead,tr,th,td,article,aside,canvas,details,embed,figure,figcaption,footer,header,hgroup,menu,nav,output,ruby,section,summary,time,mark,audio,video{font-size:100%;font:inherit;padding:0;border:0;margin:0;vertical-align:baseline}
body{line-height:1}ol,ul{list-style:none}blockquote,q{quotes:none}blockquote:before,blockquote:after,q:before,q:after{content:'';content:none}table{border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0}
article,aside,details,figcaption,figure,footer,header,hgroup,menu,nav,section{display:block}


.sticky{}
.bypostauthor{}
.wp-caption{}
.wp-caption-text{}
.gallery-caption{}
.alignright{}
.alignleft{}
.aligncenter{}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a quick fixing just apply important it should work. It will override existing background.
But make sure your path is correct.

```
body { 
    background: url('http://mysite.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/myIMG.jpg') !important;
    }
```

Comment: thnx ! it worked :)) but my background image is coming as tiled. how do i centre- aling this BG image? ALso plz tell me how do i add that text??

Comment: if you don't want to repeat just use `no-repeat` and to put in center use `center top`

Comment: I checked my blog using firebug ..it has this line html {
    margin-top: 28px !important;
}  How do i get rid of this? I dont want this margin

Comment: find that class name and search in your style where it is located. then remove

Comment: I posted the only css file I have in my wordpress new blog, can u please glance at it? I cant find 28px margin anywhere. Please help. I would be grateful. :)

Comment: I have added this line in this css just now :- html{  margin-top:0px !important;}  Its not removing that 28px margin

Answer (score 2):

if you have the element, find the class name or its id name.  If you can't find it then overwrite it, just put this code in your css

```
.class_name{ margin-top: 0 !important}
```

If that doesn't work make sure that the css file that you use to insert the code is in the last order where you declared your other css file.